# Adsense ads are not displayed on cordova webview

Tags: android, cordova, adsense

I am building a cordova app and i want to show adsense ads in it. But the ads are not displayed.

Tried Inspecting the code and fond the folling warnings

index.html code :

```
<div class="card1">
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- wasd-1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9663169732625617" data-ad-slot="7097833261" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

Error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
ads:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190612/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
ads:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load adsense into a regular Webview because Google itself will block that. Instead, get an adsense Cordova plugin for that. Also notice that to get a relevant income from that, you need thousands of impressions and hundredths of clicks per day.